# App sometimes is not present in app list of notification access of Android Settings

Tags: android, service, permissions, notifications

**Contextualization:** I have a notification listener service in my app and, for that, I start a intent for notification access android settings page, like that:

For API < 30

```
startActivity(Intent(Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS));
```

For API >= 30

```
intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_DETAIL_SETTINGS);

ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(
    context.getPackageName(),
    MyNotificationListener.class.getName()
);

intent.putExtra(
    Settings.EXTRA_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_COMPONENT_NAME,
    componentName.flattenToString()
);

startActivity(intent);
```

**Problem:** Some users are relating that my app is not listed in notification access settings page, and others that the notification access settings page does not appear when request.

The manifest has the BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE permission in the declaration of service, as expected. So, I don't know why this has been happening to specific users

```
<service
    android:name=".Services.MyNotificationListener"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true"
    android:label="MyNotificationListener"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE"
    android:process=":notifications"
    android:stopWithTask="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Comment: "and others that the notification access settings page does not appear when request" -- [the docs for `ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings#ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS) has "In some cases, a matching Activity may not exist, so ensure you safeguard against this", so that is an expected outcome. In general, you should always assume that for these Settings screens, even if the documentation does not specifically call it out.

Comment: @CommonsWare I understand, but I believe that these cases are linked to ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_DETAIL_SETTINGS, as they happen in API >=30 and started to be reported only when I started using it. Previously, it only used ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS and there were no reports in this regard.

But, taking advantage of your correct observation, is there any way to deal with this when the activity cannot be opened?

Comment: "is there any way to deal with this when the activity cannot be opened?" -- in general, other than wrapping your `startActivity()` in `try`/`catch` and displaying some sort of "sorry!" message to the user, no. Device manufacturers change the Settings app, sometimes quite dramatically, which is why Google tends to have that "a matching Activity may not exist" warning. Apparently, they're not fully testing this particular `Intent` action in the compatibility tests.

Answer (score 0):

That happens to me too, it would be really cool to find a solution or explanation